# Find top contributers from DB

Tags: php, mysql

Each post that gets created on my site get stored in a database table, inside that table is a column which lists the users username.

I'd like to find the top 10 contributers to my site, how can I count all the posts create by all users and then display the top 10 contributers in a list.

Table name: posts
Table column: username

Each post has a username entry.

Comment: @Capt Otis: you should make that an answer. it really is the way to go with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have a post count field? I assume this is some sort of forum, and users like to know their post count. Then you just select the top posters.

Then run something like...

```
 SELECT username FROM tablename ORDER BY postcount DESC limit 10
```

Answer (score 6):

```
 SELECT count(username) a,username from posts group by username order by a desc limit 10
```